# Linking numpy extensions

Tags: python, c, numpy, linker

I am trying to compile an extension with the numpy C api and setuptools.  The code compiles fine, but when running it from python, I get:

```
ImportError: ./_pyav.so: undefined symbol: PyArray_SimpleNewFromData
```

My setup.py looks roughly as follows:

```
import numpy
from setuptools import setup, Extension
...
d=[]
...
d.append(numpy.get_include())
...
Extension("_pyav",sources=["pyav.i","pyav.c"],include_dirs=d,extra_compile_args=c,extra_link_args=l,libraries=lib,swig_opts=s)
```

Obviously, the linker has not included the numpy C api objects into the resulting .so file.

Where do I get the stuff for "extra_link_args" (like "-L ..") and for "libraries" (i.e. linker switches "-llibraryname"), so that the linker can find them?

I tried fooling around with numpy.distutils.*, but found nothing there.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me,

I had forgotten "#include "numpy/arrayobject.h".